# "Object not found" Column name

Tags: r, datetime, types

I am new to Rstudio and attempting to process and analyze a dataset that I have imported.
I began by importing dataset from a CSV using readr. I used str function to confirm column names and data types. I need to change the data types of three col from chr. However, when I use the mutate and as.Date functions I receive the error object not found. When I check for col name using exist it returns FALSE. I am not sure how to work around this. Any advice appreciated.
Code chunks listed below.

```
> str(tripdata_combined)
spec_tbl_df [5,901,463 × 15] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ride_id           : chr [1:5901463] "99103BB87CC6C1BB" "EAFCCCFB0A3FC5A1" "9EF4F46C57AD234D" "5834D3208BFAF1DA" ...
 $ bike_type         : chr [1:5901463] "electric_bike" "electric_bike" "electric_bike" "electric_bike" ...
 $ started_at        : chr [1:5901463] "8/10/2021 17:15" "8/10/2021 17:23" "8/21/2021 2:34" "8/21/2021 6:52" ...
 $ ended_at          : chr [1:5901463] "8/10/2021 17:22" "8/10/2021 17:39" "8/21/2021 2:50" "8/21/2021 7:08" ...
 $ start_station_name: chr [1:5901463] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ start_station_id  : chr [1:5901463] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ end_station_name  : chr [1:5901463] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ end_station_id    : chr [1:5901463] NA NA NA NA ...
 $ start_lat         : num [1:5901463] 41.8 41.8 42 42 41.8 ...
 $ start_lng         : num [1:5901463] -87.7 -87.7 -87.7 -87.7 -87.6 ...
 $ end_lat           : num [1:5901463] 41.8 41.8 42 42 41.8 ...
 $ end_lng           : num [1:5901463] -87.7 -87.6 -87.7 -87.7 -87.6 ...
 $ user_type         : chr [1:5901463] "member" "member" "member" "member" ...
 $ ride_length       : chr [1:5901463] "0:06:55" "0:16:10" "0:16:13" "0:15:18" ...
 $ day_of_week       : num [1:5901463] 3 3 7 7 5 5 5 6 3 4 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   ride_id = col_character(),
  ..   bike_type = col_character(),
  ..   started_at = col_character(),
  ..   ended_at = col_character(),
  ..   start_station_name = col_character(),
  ..   start_station_id = col_character(),
  ..   end_station_name = col_character(),
  ..   end_station_id = col_character(),
  ..   start_lat = col_double(),
  ..   start_lng = col_double(),
  ..   end_lat = col_double(),
  ..   end_lng = col_double(),
  ..   user_type = col_character(),
  ..   ride_length = col_character(),
  ..   day_of_week = col_double()
  .. )
 - attr(*, "problems")=<externalptr>
```

```
> tripdata_combined <- tripdata_combined %>%
+     +     mutate(year = format(as.Date(started_at), "%Y")) %>% 
+     +     mutate(month = format(as.Date(started_at), "%B")) %>%
+     +     mutate(date = format(as.Date(started_at), "%d")) %>% 
+     +     mutate(day_of_week = format(as.Date(started_at), "%A")) %>% 
+     +     mutate(ride_length = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins"))
Error in as.Date(started_at) : object 'started_at' not found
> exists("started_at")
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: This isn't an RStudio question, its an R question. I've changed the tags for you.

Comment: You're going to need a bit more effort to convert those date strings to real dates. "8/10/2021 17:22" is ambiguous at best. `as.Date()` assumes year first, so 8CE (2014 years ago). `as.Date(tripdata_combined$started_at, format="%m/%d/%Y")` or maybe day/month?

Comment: For date-times you'll need to turn the character strings into date-time classes, such as POSIXct or POSIXlt, see `help("as.POSIXct")` for more on that.

Comment: `exists("started_at")` being FALSE is expected, since that's looking for an object called `started_at`, not a column name in `tripdata_combined`. I couldn't replicate your problem with a test data set (but I did show up all the other date handling issues I've put in previous comments).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way of doing it.

First, I'm going to need to fix those date formats, so write a function that does that. Given the first four that you've shown us it looks like m/d/y so try this:

```
fixDay = function(d){
    as.Date(d, format="%m/%d/%Y")
}
```

Test this at the console:

```
> fixDay(tripdata_combined$started_at)
[1] "2021-08-10" "2021-08-10" "2021-08-21" "2021-08-21"
```

Looks good.

Now write a function that does the processing and returns a modified data frame. Within the function I call `fixDay` *once* and then work with those values to extract the year, month, day, day-of-week etc.

Then I fix the times using `as.POSIXct`. I should probably have done
this in a function called `fixTimes` for testing, especially since I'm
using this twice. Anyway. They are computed, and then the difference is computed and stored in the data frame. The modified data frame is returned.

```
fixdates <- function(d){
    started_at_date = fixDay(d$started_at)
    d$year = format(started_at_date, "%Y")
    d$month = format(started_at_date, "%B")
    d$date = format(started_at_date, "%d")
    d$day_of_week = format(started_at_date, "%A")

    started_time = as.POSIXct(d$started_at, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    ended_time = as.POSIXct(d$ended_at, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    d$ride_length_computed = difftime(ended_time, started_time)

    return(d)

}
```

Now I can test this, on the whole data or on say, the first 3 rows instead of the five million...

```
> fixdates(tripdata_combined[1:3,])
           ride_id     bike_type      started_at        ended_at
1 99103BB87CC6C1BB electric_bike 8/10/2021 17:15 8/10/2021 17:22
2 EAFCCCFB0A3FC5A1 electric_bike 8/10/2021 17:23 8/10/2021 17:39
3 9EF4F46C57AD234D electric_bike  8/21/2021 2:34  8/21/2021 2:50
  start_station_name start_station_id end_station_name end_station_id start_lat
1                 NA               NA               NA             NA      41.8
2                 NA               NA               NA             NA      41.8
3                 NA               NA               NA             NA      42.0
  start_lng end_lat end_lng user_type ride_length day_of_week year  month date
1     -87.7    41.8   -87.7    member     0:06:55     Tuesday 2021 August   10
2     -87.7    41.8   -87.6    member     0:16:10     Tuesday 2021 August   10
3     -87.7    42.0   -87.7    member     0:16:13    Saturday 2021 August   21
  ride_length_computed
1               7 mins
2              16 mins
3              16 mins
```

And when I'm happy I can update my data frame:

```
tripdata_combined = fixdates(tripdata_combined)
```

None of this explains why a column in your data didn't appear to be found by a `difftime` call within a `mutate` operation though. It should work, but it didn't, and that's the reason I prefer to use the basic R data frame operations.